# How to properly define what I want to say?

Tags: phrase-request, mathematics

I'm struggling to write a concise definition of beauty(n)

Suppose we have a number consisting of an even number of digits like 12, 1234, 123456.

Examples:

beauty(1234) = 12 + 34 = 46.

beauty(123456) = 12 + 34 + 56 = 102

I said beauty(n) is the sum of every two nonoverlapping consecutive digits.

I believe what I said simply means adding all digits together. How can I properly phrase what is mentioned in the above examples?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about mathematics.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm sorry, I thought ell is a suitable place for a question like that, could you tell me where to ask in stack exchange?.

Comment: What you need is a mathematical definition and not one expressed in English.  beauty(n)=n (if n<100) ; beauty(n) = beauty(n%100) + beauty(n // 100) if n≥100 would seem to work.  Don't try for mathematical levels of clarity in a natural languge

Comment: If that is too "mathematical" just give a few examples, like you have done.  Your examples make it far more clear than a descriptions. I see a good reason to close this, but I don't see any reason to downvote!

Comment: The word "non-overlapping" should probably be hyphenated, but what does it mean? That digits that repeat are not included in the sum?

Comment: I'm closing this because ELL does not provide writing suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say

> The beauty of a number is the sum of the consecutive pairs of its digits.

But you should show an example to clarify the definition.
Beauty (abcdefgh) = ab+dc+ef+gh